# WCF as Windows service for multiple database

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, sql-server-2008, windows-services

I have a wcf service that is hosted as windows service. this service can connect to multiple database so in many cases this service will connect with multiple clients and with multiple databases. is it a best practice to host the wcf in a windows service? if not what is the best way to do that? because we are facing a serious performance issue and sometimes the service does not respond so we are forced to restart the service. Thanks in advance for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosting WCF in a Windows Service is a good idea, since no user needs to start the service or needs to be logged in.

The way you host your service should not have an impact of the performance. Lots of factors can affect your performance, look for memory leaks and race conditions, especially in regards to the multiple SQL connections.

Comment: as i can see from task manager sometimes SQL server is using about 1GB of memory! could it be from the multiple sql connections?

Comment: No, SQL is always very resource-hungry and will eat RAM until configured otherwise. Watch the memory usege and other parameters (ie. threads) of your service with the windows resource monitor, it can give you the first hint if something is out of line.